# How to convert Firebase Firestore timestamp to Zulu datetime format in Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, google-cloud-functions

I have a timestamp field in Firestore document. (refer to created_at)

[image: datetime]

I want to pass it to the server a Datetime Zulu time format like below.

```
2019-10-31T10:29:45Z
```

How do I convert Firestore timestamp to a Zulu timeformat string ?

here is my onCreate in Firebase function, upon creating a document in firestore, I read the timestamp field and print to console

```
exports.createRecord = functions.firestore
  .document(`record/{recordId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

  console.log(snap.data().created_at);

});
```

This will display in the Firebase Function logs

```
Timestamp { _seconds: 1573496322, _nanoseconds: 897429000 }
```

How can I convert this to look like in this form:

```
2019-11-01T01:36:56.233018Z
2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
2019-10-31T10:29:45Z
```

Comment: I suggest finding a date manipulation library for the language you're working with, and use to format the date.  The Firestore SDK won't be able to do this for you.  Note that Firestore timestamps also don't encode a timezone.

Comment: i think it should, i want to implement this in Firebase Function and do a http post to the server

Comment: The format you're asking about is not called "Zulu time format".  It is the [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) format, also defined as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) "complete representation extended" format.

Comment: However, it's unclear what you are asking.  You mention the `onCreate` function, but you are showing an example of `onRequest`.  I can see [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-create) that `onCreate` provides a `context`, which in turn gives a `timestamp` that is already in RFC3339 format.  So where do you need to do conversions?  If `created_at` is a field in your own data, then where is that data referenced in your code?  Please edit your question to show exactly the code you are trying.  Thanks.

Comment: i havent implemented the onCreate() function yet, so this is something todo (will get to that part when we figure out but oncreate should trigger an insert into firestore). upon of the document creation which includes a timestamp, i want to pass that info to the server side, and the server requires a timeformat of this type "2019-10-31T10:29:45Z". if you say timestamp is already converted to  RFC3339, then this question is irrelevant. which means i need to just try it out and update on this once i figure out the oncreate, and extracting the timestamp from the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Firestore Timestamp](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/api/timestamp.ts) object is not an extension of the Javascript `Date` object. But it contains a [`toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#to-date) method to get a regular `Date` object, which you can use to easily format the date that you need into a string.

Cloud functions run with no timezone offset (UTC time). So you effectively get Zulu time when you format your dates. Use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to get a string on the wanted format

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Try to change your code above to this and you will see the output that you expect.

```js
exports.createRecord = functions.firestore
  .document(`record/{recordId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

  console.log(snap.data().created_at.toDate().toISOString());

});
```

**Additional resources**

[Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) is a great and easy to use library if you have more complex need to manipulate dates or work with timezones. It adds some overhead to your function dependenceis, but it really helps readability of your code.

Comment: toDate() seems to work but not for .toISOString(). here is the error: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/91a00fb42b616fa5283653e60fac2a54. Im interested to see toISOString(), any idea how to get it working ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer above: the Firestore timestamp is not a JavaScript date. You must call `toDate` first. See the class references in my answer above